# ajax passing parameter to javascript/php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I experience a weird problem in this code, actually it works for 1 second and then not anymore.. maybe some variable/function is not correctly declared and is causing this strange thing..

I have in my index.php this piece of code. If I put hardcode inside the function myfunc par1 and par2 set to zero then everything behaves correctly, means loadfunc.php is correcly called with those parameters, while if try the code I posted I see that loadfunc.php is called once correctly and so I can see the correct output for only 1 second..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function myfunc(par1, par2)
    {

        var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis2').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 1000);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'loadfunc.php' + '?par1=' + par1 + '&par2=' + par2);
            $http.send(null);
        }
    }

  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function() {myfunc("0","0");}, 1000);
 </script>
```

Comment: is par1 and par2 correct. try yo console.log the url you are sending. i have a feeling that par1 or par2 contains something different after the first call.

Comment: yes in fact in the console at the beginning I see that par1 and par2 are initialized to zero but after I see then "undefined"! but who would be responsible to change par1 and par2? when I call myfunc I put them to zeros, I don't understand why and how they change values..

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 1000);
```

Resets the timeout, but doesn't set up the parameters, which is why they show up as undefined.